SDL2 Window not showing (C - Debian 12)
I created a simple project with just a window, compiled it and executed it:
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_events.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_pixels.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_video.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
    printf("Failed to init video: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow(
    "Chip 8 - Emulator",
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
    300,
    300,
    SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE
  );

  if (window == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to create window: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  SDL_Event e;
  bool quit = false;
  while (!quit) {
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)) {
      if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
        quit = true;
      }

      if (e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
        quit = true;
      }

      if (e.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN) {
        quit = true;
      }
    }
  }

  SDL_Quit();
  return 0;
}

I have no errors at all but when I am running my program, no window shows up.
I compiled everything using this command:
gcc -o a.out main.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2)

Also I am running Debian 12 (with Gnome).
I tried to compile my program on Wayland and X but the problem remains.
I also tried to add a delay after the SDL_CreateWindow but still nothing

Put some printf() in your code - if it's anything like on my computer, you're getting a keyboard event. This is a general debugging tip. Put loads of printf() everywhere, logging everything your code does. You can take them out later once it all works.

@pmacfarlane a simpler solution is to use a good debugger. Printf works but is tedious and doesn't actually show you what the code is doing and where values are being stored.
Mephilia, I'd recommend taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems?noredirect=1&lq=1

Replace the SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE flag with 0

I just tried to change the SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE but still nothing.
Also, when putting some printf to check everything, nothing weird appears expect for one thing:
I have 3 iterations on the while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)) then nothing

@Mephilia: I suggest that you put three different printf statements immediately above each quit = true; line to see if any of these lines are being triggered, and if yes, to see which one is being triggered.

I just tried but none of them is called

@Mephilia: My only explanation is that you have made a mistake in inserting the printf statements or in interpreting them. I suggest that you [edit] your question to add the code with all of the printf statements and to also post the exact output of your code. I also suggest that you add a printf immediately before the call to SDL_Quit. You don't have to overwrite your original question; you can add this information to the bottom of the question, if you want.

Is the SDL you're compiling/linking against self-built or distro-provided?  What does the demo program at the bottom of this answer output?

Why are you #includeing SDL with a SDL2 directory prefix on the headers?  pkg-config's --cflags should have spit out an -I flag (ex: -I/usr/include/SDL2) that enabled prefix-less (#include <SDL.h>) usage.

Thank you @genpfault this link fixed my problem ! I think I was missing some dependencies :)
